# How to get size of widgets

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am developing a PyQt5 application however I am having issues with the heights of the widgets. Below is a simplified version of my issue:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.showMaximized()
        self.setStyleSheet("QWidget {background: blue;}")
        print(self.frameGeometry().height())
        self.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app = App()
    window.setStyle(QStyleFactory.create("Fusion"))
    window.exec_()
```

Here I create a window and maximise it. Using a tkinter window, it tells me the height maximised is 841, which is the size of my screen, however the PyQt5 application prints the height to be 519. Is this an issue with the `self.showMaximized()` method, or some other issue.

Comment: If you're referring to the output of `print(self.frameGeometry().height())`, that is not always reliable, especially when the widget is still being "mapped" (showed the first time). Why do you need to know the size during initialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resizing is not instantaneous in Qt. What Qt does is take the information from showMaximized to activate the flag of the native window (library that depends on each OS) then after a time T the OS applies that flag and sends it the new geometry. So in your case you have to give it a delay to get the correct information.

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QStyleFactory, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer


class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setStyleSheet("QWidget {background: blue;}")
        self.showMaximized()

        QTimer.singleShot(100, self.calculate)

    def calculate(self):
        print(self.frameGeometry().height())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app = App()
    window.setStyle(QStyleFactory.create("Fusion"))
    window.exec_()
```

On the other hand, if your objective is to know the size of the initial screen then you should not use a QWidget for that since it will depend on the time it takes for Qt and the native library to create the native window, instead use the Screen class :

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import QGuiApplication

if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = QApplication(sys.argv)
    print(QGuiApplication.primaryScreen().availableGeometry().height())
```